# Refactoring a HTML class collector?

Tags: ruby, html, ruby-on-rails

I have following HTML class collector. Is there a better way than `[]tap` for this?

```
def tr_classes(user)
  classes = [].tap do |c|
    c << "error" if user.company.nil?
    c << "disabled" if user.disabled?
  end
  if classes.any?
    " class=\"#{classes.join(" ")}\""
  end
end

<tr<%= tr_classes(user) %>>
  <td><%= user.name %></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notes:

- This `tap` usage is not uncommon to see but IMHO it's very, very dubious. You can use a functional approach (see code below).
- I wouldn't return the string along with the attribute, just the array of classes (which Rails3 helpers understand).

I'd write:

```
def tr_classes(user)
  [
    ("error" if !user.company),
    ("disabled" if user.disabled?),
  ].compact.presence
end
```

Tables are usually easier to build from helpers. You now would use the function that way:

```
content_tag(:tr, :class => tr_classes(user)) do
  content_tag(:td, user.name)
end
```

Comment: Glad somebody suggested `content_tag`; I find opening a `<%= %>` to mess with the individual attributes of an opening HTML tag to be particularly awful.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean a "better way" than `tap`? **Why** are you using `tap` at all? Initialize an array. Conditionally append items to it. This pattern is as old as time, and there is no reason to shoe-horn in a Ruby-esque solution.

```
classes = [].tap do |c|
  c << "error" if user.company.nil?
  c << "disabled" if user.disabled?
end
```

vs

```
classes = []
classes << "error" if user.company.nil?
classes << "disabled" if user.disabled?
```

You've added **so much** complexity, both functionally and visually, for literally no gain. You've produced *more* and *uglier* code.

Comment: I also dislike this use of `tap`, but I guess that the OP is using it because it's not uncommon to see. The only good thing about this pattern is that side-effects are confined into a block, that maybe useful with other objects, with an array it's completely overkill.